# std::map<K, V>.clear() crashes in corrupted double-linked list

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdmap

So i got the variable

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> m_map;
```

During the program shutdown routine, I'd like to exploit the wonderful *smart pointer* [property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) which should (if I'm not wrong) take care of the destruction of `MyClass` instances, once their own last reference is destroyed.

So I'm just calling `m_map.clear()`, but this

1. **SOMETIME** produces the aforementioned

   ```
   corrupted double-linked list
   ```
2. while in other cases (unknown thus uncontrolled variable) works correctly,
3. and finally in other cases (controlled variable; in facts, different program configuration) produces

   ```
   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error*'
   ```

I'd gladly receive at least some hint on approaches to the problem. Since the program is strongly multithreaded (and I know very little of it) I'm wondering if the deletion of that pointer to `MyClass` instance would interfere with something else.

Comment: Have you tried using valgrind or gdb to analyze your code?

Comment: We cannot know what the issue is without seeing your "sometime", "other cases" and "other cases".

Comment: You should not see the new smart pointers as just auto-deleting pointers, but instead in an ownership perspective. Can a resource have only one owner at a time? Then use `std::unique_ptr`. Can a resource have multiple simultaneous owners? Then use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: A Basic but important question: As you wrote it is multithreaded; so you are doing synchronization, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of error is caused when you're calling at least 2 methods that affect the structure from at least 2 different threads.

For example, calling clear() on std::map will change the structure of the map itself (remove all items). And if you have another thread that's using that map at the same time (IE. looping over it, inserting, etc.) then you'll have the exception you're seeing.
The exception is caused because the std::map structure is in an invalid state (map nodes are in the middle of changing positions) while you're trying to access it.

The simplest solution would be to hold a lock whenever you access that map object.